# When is a ChannelHandlerContext handed to a ChannelHandler not that ChannelHandler's own context?

Tags: netty

Here is a (permanent) link to an example in the wild of the issue I have a question about, drawn from Netty's own examples.  The example in question is not itself important, just the fact that it shows a pattern I'm wondering about:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/b26a61acd1bde5b6fca21026cd9123a38f277ad6/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http2/helloworld/multiplex/server/Http2ServerInitializer.java#L97-L103

I've excerpted it below:

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpMessage msg) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ctx.pipeline();
    ChannelHandlerContext thisCtx = pipeline.context(this);
    /* ... */
```

Here we have a `ChannelInboundAdapter` that is passed a `ChannelHandlerContext`.  Fine.

The first two lines of the method I've excerpted here, though, jump through some hoops to acquire "the right" `ChannelHandlerContext`, implying (to me, anyway) that the `ChannelHandlerContext` that is supplied to this method is somehow not one that "belongs to" this `ChannelHandler`.

Under what circumstances is this sort of hoop-jumping required?

Comment: I've been using a lot of netty recently and this "hoop-jumping" seems unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up... This is actually "a bug" in the example and totally unnecessary. Just use ctx :)

Proposed fix to the examples:

https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/9276